# help with wrapping text in a table, and making a solid line at the far right corner

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable, wrap

I am trying to wrap text in a longtable to achieve the below:
[image]

however, when using the code below, I get this:
[image]

May I please ask how to wap the text in the headings to appear over two rows, and also how to achieve a solid vertical line at the right hand side of the table, instead of the dashed line?

```
    \begin{longtable}{|c||ccccc|}
    \toprule
    \hline 
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Sample Name} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Temperatures (\textsuperscript{o}C)} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Peak Height (\%)} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries CO\textsubscript{2} Reactivity (\%)}\\
    \cline{2-4}
    & Ignition & Peak & Burnout \\
    \hline 
    \hline 
    \endfirsthead
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument to `\multirow` allows you to specify a width. If you just use `{*}`, as you did, it'll make the cell big enough for the full contents, but if you specify a width, it'll allow for wrapping. (But you need to tell it how wide to go before wrapping.)

Because this introduces a parbox into the cell, you need to use `\centering` again to make it centered. (However, `\centering` redefines `\\`, so in the last column you need to use `\arraybackslash` to restore it to its normal use in tables.)

Commands like `\toprule`, `\midrule`, etc., come from the booktabs package. The booktabs package is incompatible with using vertical lines in tables. Instead of those commands, just stick to `\hline`, `\cline`, etc. (Or you could use *only* those commands and remove the vertical lines altogether; generally vertical lines in tables are not needed.)

However, the reason you weren't getting a full vertical line at the far right in the second row is that you didn't have the final two cells in that row. Just put in `& &` for empty cells in that row.

Here's a suggestion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{|c|ccccc|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering\bfseries Sample Name} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Temperatures ($^\mathbf{\circ}$C)} &
    \multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering\bfseries Peak Height (\%)} & 
    \multirow{2}{2.7cm}{\centering\arraybackslash\bfseries CO\textsubscript{2} Reactivity (\%)}\\
    \cline{2-4}
    & Ignition & Peak & Burnout & & \\
    \hline 
    \endhead
A                   & 517.56 & 668.61 & 782.66 & 6.12 & 13.03 \\
B                   & 522.48 & 646.93 & 772.85 & 5.90 & 14.00 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: output table]

You might consider getting rid of the `(%)` in the last two columns, or even moving the percent signs into the content rows, since as is they make the columns wider than they need to be, which is a bit ugly. (And pushing them down a line would also be ugly.) Your call.

I removed the double lines, which I find ugly, but you can restore them if you feel strongly about them.

There are possibly other improvements that could be made (e.g., use a sans font like the first image, use the siunitx package for columns aligned at the decimal point, etc.) But I'll leave it here for now.

Comment: thank you for this! do you happen to know how to put a continuous vertical line on the far right corner please? I get a dashed line! I've added a picture of this in the updated question

Comment: The code I posted generates a continuous vertical line, and I explained in my answer why your original code didn't generate one in the second header row. You haven't posted the full code for the new image, so I can't say for sure why you're not getting one, but make sure you have enough `&`s in each row to generate a cell for every column, even if they're blank.

Answer (score 2):

- Code for your table can be much simpler and concise, if for table you use the `tabularray` package.
- By using `tabularray` you will avoid all problems with your code fragment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {my long table ...},
  label = {tab:long}
                ]{hline{1,3,Z} = 1pt,
                  hline{2} = solid,
                   colspec = {l *{6}{X[c]}},
                    row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
                     vspan = even,
                   rowhead = 2
                }
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    {Sample\\ Name}
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Temperatures (\si{\celsius}) 
        &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    Peak Height (\%) 
                    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    \ce{CO2} Reactivity (\%)    \\
    &   Ignition 
        &   Peak 
            &   Burnout 
                &   &                               \\
%% table body
A   & 517.56 & 668.61 & 782.66 & 6.12  & 13.03  \\
B   & 522.48 & 646.93 & 772.85 & 5.90  & 14.00  \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- Since you not provide examples of tables content, I stole it from @frabjous answer.
- If numbers in columns has different number of digits, you may consider zo align them at decimal points by employing `siunitx` package. In such case, the table preamble can be (where you should accommodate `table-format` to numbers of integer and decimal digits of numbers in columns):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {my long table ...},
  label = {tab:long}
                ]{hline{1,3,Z} = 1pt,
                  hline{2} = solid,
                   colspec = {@{} l *{6}{X[c, si = {table-format=3.2}]} @{}},
                    row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries, guard},
                    row{2} = {guard},
                     vspan = even,
                   rowhead = 2
                }
%% table body
```